# Replace all values in a row which are the top 1% quantile

Tags: r, replace, quantile

I have a dataframe consisting of 395 rows and 4973 columns, sorted by months. My Dataframe Test looks something like that:

```
Date     FirmA FirmB FirmC FirmD 
01-2015  20    NA    100   1000 
02-2015  21    502   2000  9378   
03-2015  22    3     2     100
04-2015  24    7000  5     1000
```

I would like to replace in each row the top 1% quantile of each row with NA.
It should look like follwing:

```
Date     FirmA FirmB FirmC FirmD 
01-2015  20    NA    100   NA 
02-2015  21    502   2000  NA   
03-2015  22    3     2     NA
04-2015  24    NA  5     1000
```

I managed to calcualate the quantile of each row and put it into a new column Test$Quantile.

```
Test$Quantile <- apply(Test[-1],1,quantile,probs=c(.99), na.rm=TRUE)

Date      FirmA FirmB FirmC FirmD Quantile
01-2015   20    NA    100   1000  982.00
02-2015   21    502   2000  9378  9156.66
03-2015   22    3     2     100   97.66
04-2015   24    7000  5     1000  6820.00
```

However, I don't know how to replace all values in a row which are larger than that quantile value. And I also think there must be an easier solution than by forming a new column.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `replace` to replace the values to NA that is greater than the `quantile` for each row

```
Test[-1] <- t(apply(Test[-1], 1, function(x) 
       replace(x, x> quantile(x, probs = 0.99, na.rm =TRUE), NA)))
Test
#     Date FirmA FirmB FirmC FirmD
#1 01-2015    20    NA   100    NA
#2 02-2015    21   502  2000    NA
#3 03-2015    22     3     2    NA
#4 04-2015    24    NA     5  1000
```

Comment: Perfect thank you very much! Will accept as soon as possible :)